# How to use react-toastr?

Tags: reactjs, toastr

I am trying to user a single `ToastContainer` for all my components in a `ReactJS` app but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I tried:

```
let container;

ReactDOM.render(
  <App container={container}>
    <ToasterContainer ref={ref => (container = ref)} />
  </App>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

However, I get an error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Anybody have any tips on how to do it?

I am open to using any other libraries that may play better with a React app.

I should also mention that my aim is to be able to display toasts from modules that only contain helper functions but do not render anything per se. The biggest problem I have so far with `react-toastr` is that it requires the `ToasterContainer` component to be rendered first to be able to display any toasts. My ideal solution would be something I can create like this:

```
let toastr = new Toastr(/* some options */);
toastr.show(message);
```

Comment: I can suggest you a better plugin [react-toastify](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify)

Comment: Doesn't it have the same problem? It requires rendering a component first?

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is not with the toaster part,

```
let container;
ReactDOM.render(<App container={container}>
```

Here you have created and without initialising `container` you have assigned it to container thus container has value undefined.

If you are trying to implement `react-toastify`, you dont need to pass the ref, simply add `<ToastContainer />` in your main component,

```
App = () =>(
  //add your routes here
  <ToasterContainer/>
)
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: So what solution would you recommend?

Comment: I dont know why you are using `container={container}` there. If that is not needed, remove it and try running.

Comment: Because I want to pass ’container’ on to my other components so they can show toasts when needed and I don’t know how else to do that.

Comment: What is the value of the container?

Comment: Well I would like for it to be the reference to the ToastContainer so that the child components can use it to toast messages.

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post what I would actually like to do is to pass the reference to the ToastContainer to all my other components and modules, even those that don't render anything. If you have any suggestions on how to do that that would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: react-toastify is indeed a good API and is very easy to use for implementing toastr. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify
Above link shows how we can implement and use it. There is live demo app as well to test the toastr notification.